# change column position in a text linux file

Tags: linux, sorting, text

I'm looking for a solution to change the position of a column in linux.
In my particular case from the 1st position to the last position.

```
qty | sender | recipient | some email subject

sender | recipient | some email subject | qty
```

If I have a file with the following content:

```
4 | one | two | the first subject
5 | one | four | other interesting subject
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
one | two | the first subject | 4
one | four | other interesting subject | 5
```

Delimiter is "|". It is not important if I have "|" at the beginning or at the end of each row.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing is a classic work for sed:

```
sed 's/\(^[^|]*\)|\(.*$\)/\2 | \1/' yourFile.txt >newFile.txt
```

To save the changes directly in the same file:

```
sed -i 's/\(^[^|]*\)|\(.*$\)/\2 | \1/' yourFile.txt
```

- ^[^|]*  -->  for beginning of the line until the first vertical bar.
- .*$     -->  any remaining characters until the end of the line.
- \(  \)  -->  This is to save these parts and recover later with \{number}
- \2 | \1 --> Recover saved part with the new order.

To know more about sed [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Comment: Thank you, blasher. Works like charm! Big Thank You!